# Sweedler Notation: $\eta\epsilon$ is the identity element of the convolution product

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification, convolution, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

1. **Proof attempt**
   Let $(A, \mu, \eta) $ be an algebra and $(C, \Delta, \epsilon) $ be a coalgebra, both over the same field $k$.
   Define the convolution product $$*: \mathrm{Hom}(C,A)\otimes \mathrm{Hom}(C,A) \rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(C,A); \qquad f \otimes g \mapsto \mu \circ (f \otimes g)\circ \Delta.$$
   I saw (a less detailed version of) the following attempt to prove that $\eta \circ \epsilon$ is the identity element with respect to the convolution product:
   $$(f * (\eta \epsilon))(c)=\sum\limits_{(c)}f(c^{(1)})(\eta\epsilon)(c^{(2)})= \sum\limits_{(c)}f(c^{(1)})(\eta(\epsilon (c^{(2)})1_k)=\sum\limits_{(c)}f(c^{(1)})(\epsilon(c^{(2)})\eta(1_k))=
   \sum\limits_{(c)}f(c^{(1)})\epsilon(c^{(2)})=f(c).$$
2. **Question**

- Is that proof attempt correct?
- Specifically: The third step holds because of the linearity of the unit $\eta$; the fourth step due to the defining property of the unit (i.e. unitality); the last due to the defining property of the counit - correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that for every linear map $f$, it is often useful to write $A \otimes f$ and $f \otimes A$ instead of $Id_A \otimes f$ and
$f \otimes Id_A$ respectively, my version of this proof is the following:

$$f * \eta\epsilon = \mu \circ (f \otimes \eta\epsilon) \circ \Delta = \mu \circ (A \otimes \eta) \circ (f\otimes \mathbb{k}) \circ (C \otimes \epsilon) \circ \Delta = r_A \circ (f\otimes \mathbb{k}) \circ (r_C)^{-1} = f$$ where $$r_A: A \otimes \mathbb{k} \rightarrow A\\ a\otimes k \mapsto ka$$

The second identity follows from a trick that's very usual in this type of proofs and it is verifiable by direct computation:

$$\mu \circ (f \otimes \eta\epsilon) \circ \Delta (c) = \sum f(c_1) \eta\epsilon(c_2)$$

while

$$\mu \circ (A \otimes \eta) \circ (f\otimes \mathbb{k}) \circ (C \otimes \epsilon) \circ \Delta (c) = \\
    = \mu \circ (A \otimes \eta) \circ (f\otimes \mathbb{k}) (\sum c_1 \otimes \epsilon(c_2)) =  \\
    = \mu \circ (A \otimes \eta) (\sum f(c_1)\otimes \epsilon(c_2)) = \\
    = \mu (\sum f(c_1)\otimes \eta\epsilon(c_2)) =\\
    =\sum f(c_1) \eta\epsilon(c_2)
$$

Comment: Why does the second step hold? That is: What do $A \otimes \eta$, $f \otimes k$ and $C \otimes \epsilon$ even mean? $\otimes$ is a functor associating a vector space to a pair of vector spaces, and a linear map to a pair of linear maps. $A$ is a vector space, while $\eta$ is a linear map. Or is $A$ a short hand here?

Comment: @M.C I edited. Is it clearer? I don't understand why you say that $\otimes$ is a functor that goes to a pair of vector spaces. $\otimes: V \times W \rightarrow V\otimes W$ where $V\otimes W$ is a single vector space.

Comment: I didn't say that "$\otimes$ is a functor that goes to a pair of vector spaces." Rather I wrote, that it "associates one vector space to a pair of vector spaces." In other words, it takes two vector spaces/linear maps and maps them to one vector space/linear map. Just like you wrote.

Comment: @M.C. ok, right. So we meant the same thing! Perfect.

Comment: If you mean $id_A \otimes \eta$ by $A \otimes \eta$ and $f \otimes id_k$ by $f \otimes k$ (and so on), then your edit makes it indeed clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @M.C. Yes, I mean $id_A \otimes \eta$. You're welcome!