# Proving uniqueness of antipodes in Hopf algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Let $(H,\mu,\nu,\Delta,\epsilon)$ be a Bialgebra where H is the vector space, $\mu, \nu$ are the product and unit whilst $\Delta, \epsilon$ are the coproduct and counit. Now, for $f,g \in end(H)$ define $f@g \in end(H)$ by $f@g=\mu(f \otimes g)\Delta(x)=\Sigma_{(x)}f(x')g(x'')$ (via Sweedler notation).

An element $S \in end(H)$ is called an antipode if

$S@id_H=id_H@S=\nu\circ\epsilon$

If a Bialgebra has an antipode, then it is unique. To see this, suppose $S,T$ are antipodes for the bialgebra $H$. Then we have:

$S = S@(\nu\epsilon)=S@(id_H@T)=(S@id_H)@T=(\nu\epsilon)@T=T$

Can somebody explain to me the first equality? Why do we get $S = S@(\nu\epsilon)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that an antipode for a bialgebra $H$ is a linear map $S:H \rightarrow H$ which is a convolution inverse of $id_H$.

> We have to remember that the unit for the convolution product is
> $$1_{\text{End}(H)}=\nu \circ\epsilon $$ Proof: $$f*(\nu\epsilon) = \mu \circ(f \otimes \nu\epsilon) \circ \Delta = \mu \circ (A \otimes \nu) \circ (f \otimes \mathbb{k})\circ (C \otimes \epsilon) \circ \Delta = \\= r_A \circ (f \otimes \mathbb{k}) \circ(r_C)^{-1} = f$$ (if you miss the second equality you can read a complete explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768735/sweedler-notation-eta-epsilon-is-the-identity-element-of-the-convolution-pro/3768868?noredirect=1#comment7757889_3768868))

So, $\forall f \in \text{End}(H)$, the following holds (because $f*id = f$ in every algebraic context): $$f * 1_{\text{End}(H)}= f$$

Now, take $S \in \text{End}(H)$ and write the same thing:
$$S = S * 1_{\text{End}(H)}$$

but $1_{\text{End}(H)}=\nu \circ\epsilon $, so

$$S = S *\nu \epsilon$$

Comment: I don't understand the counit $\nu$ enough. It seems weird to me that $\nu\circ\epsilon=1_{End(H)}$ for some reason... Like $\epsilon$ sends an element of the algebra to the base field, and then $\nu$ can take that element in the basefield and return the original element of the algebra?? Just is quite mystifying to me still. Thanks for your response though it helps

Comment: Even $f*1_{End(H)}=f$ is strange to me. I mean, we have $$f*1_{End(H)}=\Sigma f(x')x''$$ which then equals $f(x)$?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa $\nu$ is the unit (not the counit), as you well said in your main text. $\nu: \mathbb{k} \rightarrow E_H, k \mapsto k \cdot 1_{E_H}$. The fact that $f*1_{\text{End}(h)} = f $ follows from direct computation. Can you take it from there or do you need an edit to my question?

Comment: Why don't you go ahead and fill in the details for me, i'm quite slow :D

Comment: It seems to me like when you apply $\epsilon$ to an element of the algebra you would lose information that you can't recover by applying $\nu$

Comment: I see now that $S*\nu\epsilon=S*Id_{End(H)}$. Is there a way of showing $\nu \epsilon = 1_{End(H)}$ without using the convolution product? It still seems to me that by composing $\nu\epsilon$ you factor $H$ through its base field, and it's strange to me that you can get back all of what you started with.

Comment: So if $\nu\circ\epsilon=Id_H$ then $\epsilon$ must be an injective map... really??

Comment: @HakuNa MaTaTa You want remember that we are working in $\text{End}(H)$, so the composition is the identity seen as a function from$H$ to $H$ (perhaps my previous comment had confused you, I'm sorry), so we have not found $id_H$ but rather $id_{\text{End}(H)}$. Perhaps you can open another question if it is not clear yet.

Comment: Right. It's still weird though >.< Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

We can in fact prove this using a commutative diagram, so that the result generalizes for all Hopf monoids in symmetric monoidal categories.

[image: diagram for uniqueness of antipode]

Here, $I$ denotes the monoidal unit (that is, the base field). The two top quadrilaterals commute by the properties of a monoidal category; the two triangles commute by the properties of the unit $\eta$ and counit $\varepsilon$; the bottom quadrilateral commutes because $T$ is an antipode. Therefore, we have proven that:

$$S=(\mu\circ(1_H\otimes\mu))\circ(S\otimes1_H\otimes T)\circ((1_H\otimes\Delta)\circ\Delta).$$

In a very similar manner we can also prove that

$$T=(\mu\circ(\mu\otimes1_H))\circ(S\otimes1_H\otimes T)\circ((\Delta\otimes1_H)\circ\Delta).$$

But by associativity and co-associativity, this means $S=T$.