# In a Hopf algebra $H$, unit $\circ$ counit = Identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $(H,\mu,\nu,\Delta,\epsilon,S)$ be a Hopf algebra where the convolution is denoted by $*$.

Then $S=S*\nu\epsilon$ and thus $\nu\epsilon = 1_{End(H)}$. This would imply that $\epsilon$ is injective and $\nu$ is surjective. I am surprised  that this mysterious $\epsilon$ is injective. Can somebody please help me to understand why that is?

For more context, check my previous post:[Proving uniqueness of antipodes in Hopf algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3769883/proving-uniqueness-of-antipodes-in-hopf-algebras/3769913?noredirect=1#comment7758422_3769913)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The counit is **never** injective and the unit is **never** surjective, unless $H$ is of dimension $1$. It's the other way around: the unit is always injective while the counit is always surjective. After all (by the axioms of bialgebra) $\epsilon\circ\nu=id_K$ where $K$ is the underlying field while $id_K(x)=x$ is the identity function.

I think that the confusion comes from the fact that "$1_{End(H)}$" in the other question **is not the identity function $id_H(x)=x$**. Moreover $1_{End(H)}(x)\neq x$ for at least one $x\in H$, unless $H$ is of dimension $1$. Actually the dimension (over $K$) of the image of $1_{End(H)}$ is $1$, regardless of $H$.

The $1_{End(H)}$ endomorphism is the identity but with respect to convolution, not composition. In fact $1_{End(H)}=\nu\circ\epsilon$ **is the definition of** $1_{End(H)}$. Which then is proven to be the neutral element of the convolution operator.

Comment: Man... So given any $x \in H$, we have $\nu\epsilon(x)=x$. It just STILL seems so weird to me that we can take an element in the algebra, send it to the base field, and then recover that element back!!! Seems like we shouldn't be able to factor the algebra through it's base field and then still get the whole algebra back >.< my intuition is really lacking in this stuff

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa I just told you that $\nu\epsilon(x)=x$ is false (athough $\epsilon\nu(x)=x$ is true) and that $1_{End(H)}$ is not the identity function: $1_{End(H)}(x)\neq x$. What exactly is unclear in my post? Also the image of $1_{End(H)}$ is of dimension $1$. So yes, $1_{End(H)}$ does lose information unless $H$ is of dimension $1$.